# How to setup TensorFlow Lite on Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Recently, I have built TensorFlow Lite (v1.12.1) from source using the instructions provided by [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/28863), which gives me a **libtensorflow-lite.a** file.

Now, I have been trying to set up a Visual Studio Project to use TensorFlow Lite on C++. Unfortunately, there is not much material about it on TensorFlow's issues or TensorFlow Lite's documentation. Following the instructions from [this tutorial](https://mechatronicsblog.com/tensorflow-lite-integration-with-qt-and-v-play-for-multi-platform-machine-learning-apps-on-ios-and-android/), I'm getting these errors:

[image]

Here are my project settings:

**General Settings**:

[image: general]

---

**C/C++**:
[image]

my **Additional Include Directories**:

```
C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-lite
C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\tools\make\downloads\eigen
C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\tools\make\downloads\gemmlowp
C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\tools\make\downloads\neon_2_sse
C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\tools\make\downloads\farmhash\src
C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\tools\make\downloads\flatbuffers\include
C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\tools\make\downloads\fft2d
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

---

**Linker Options**:

[image]

my **Additional Dependencies**:

```
C:\tensorflow\tensorflow-lite\tensorflow\lite\tools\make\gen\aarch64_armv8-a\lib\libtensorflow-lite.a
%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing "including directories" or other project settings. So, have someone configured TensorFlow Lite on C++ before?

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Visual Studio with Clang and the Android NDK, but the error you're observing would manifest if you're not building with a C++11 configuration. I do see that in your project options ("-std=c++11"), is there any way you can provide the full build command that gets passed to clang?